# Setup calendar in Autosys jil

Tags: scripting, autosys, jil

I have below requirement in Autosys

1. The businessdates calendar is stored in the csv file. The businesdates will exclude weekends and US holidays.
2. I have to create a autosys job in such a way that the autosys job should only execute on above business day calendar.
3. On non-business days(weekends and holidays) the job shouldn't get triggered .

Thanks

Comment: calendar is an yearly activity, based on the csv file create a Autosys calendar and then assign them to application jobs.

Comment: https://ftpdocs.broadcom.com/cadocs/0/h042533e.pdf - Autosys Documentation